# Validate a string which can only contain letters, numbers and the underscore character

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am trying to validate a string which can only contain letters, numbers and the underscore character. No spaces, no emoji or whatsoever. In javascript, I use this regular expression to check

```
var re = /^\w+$/
```

but in Swift, I keep getting this error

```
Incorrect argument label in call (have 'options:', expected 'coder:')
```

at this line

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/^\w+$/", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Below is my code in Swift

```
let testString = "Hello world"
do
{
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "/^\w+$/", options: .caseInsensitive)
    if regex.matches(in: testString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, testString.count)).count > 0 {
        print("Accept")
    }else{
        print("Not Accept")
    }
}
catch {

}
```

Comment: You don't need the `/` in the regex pattern

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "letter" and "number"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern has to be written as `^\\w+$`

The wrapping `/` in Javascript are just a Javascript syntax for defining a regular expression, they are not part of the regular expression itself.

Since this is a string, we also have to escape the `\` character (in Javascript you would have to do it too if you used a string to define the expression).

Also note this can be written more easily as:

```
if testString.range(of: "^\\w+$", options: [.regularExpression, .caseInsensitive]) != nil {
}
```

(`.caseInsensitive` is not actually needed for `\w` class because it already contains both uppercase and lowercase characters).